# Why varying the frequency of a propagation wave in a non-dispersive media doesn’t change it’s propagation velocity?

Tags: waves, acoustics, dimensional-analysis, speed, dispersion

> Why varying the frequency of a propagation wave in a non-dispersive media doesn’t change it’s propagation velocity?

Before anything, I want to note that I’ve seen already similar questions on this site but none have the perspective I give it to it. It may sound as a dumb question since I’ve learnt by heart that the propagation velocity in travelling waves in non-dispersive media don’t get affected by variations of frequency, but only to the media characteristics, such as tension. I can believe it but at the same time it sounds weird mathematically, since for me $$v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$ and since $T=\frac{1}{f}$, it makes sense to me that $$v=\sqrt{\frac{1}{f\mu}}$$ so then say we have a wave through a chord that propagates at a frequency $f$ and then through that chord, we decelerate so that the frequency is now $f’=2f$, it’s totally legal for me *mathematically* that then $$v’=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2f\mu}}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$$ so it does vary, of course I know this doesn’t actually happen, but I’m wondering why it is still legal mathematically to obtain this contradictory result.

Comment: In your first equation for the velocity I suspect that $T$ is the tension and not the period.  So $T\ne 1/f$.

Comment: @Farcher appreciate it but can you check the comment to the post below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @Farcher's comment (answer?), $T$ is not the period.

When confused by an equation: do a dimensional analysis. Were $T$ a period, then the dimensions of:

$$ \sqrt{\frac T {\mu}} $$

would be

$$ \Big(\frac{[T]}{[M]/[L]}\Big)^{\frac 1 2}$$

which is an inverse velocity per mass, square-rooted. Not a velocity.

Try it with $T$ having dimensions of tension and see what happens.

Comment: oh my god that’s so dumb. Okay thanks but *still* can have the same argument with the equation $v=\lambda f$, mathematically it makes sense to me that if the frecuency is doubled, then $v’=\lambda (2f)=2v$. How is that? It is really the same question but with an actual true formula, still as confused as before

Comment: if $ f\rightarrow 2f$, then $\lambda \rightarrow \lambda/2 $, so the equation is $v=constant$ is a constraint on the product $f\lambda$.

Comment: $T$ suffers from ominastic profusion, it's over worked: temperature, period, tension, kinetic energy...

Comment: If $v' = \lambda (2f) = 2v$, then the medium is dispersive.

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out in a comment the $T$ in the velocity equation could be the tension in a string rather than a time period.

The equation you quoted $v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$ could be for the speed of a wave $v$ along a string with tension $T$ and mass per unit length $\mu$.
As written the speed of a wave does not depend on wavelength or frequency, the speed is a constant as long as the tension and the mass per unit length stay constant.

Suppose that when the frequency is $f$ the length of one complete wave on the string (wavelength) is $\lambda$.

What will happen if the frequency was doubled to $2f$?
A selected point on the string would oscillate with a frequency $2f$.
The "information" as to what the string is doing at the selected point would travel along the string at a speed $v$.
In a period of time equivalent to two oscillations of the selected point the "information" as to what the selected point had been doing would have travelled down the string and two complete waves would have been produced occupying a distance equal to one wavelength of a wave of frequency $f$.
Those two complete waves produced by the point oscillating at frequency $2f$ correspond to two wavelengths at the new frequency and so are equal to half the wavelength when the sting was oscillating at frequency $f$.

Thus, $(2f)\cdot(\frac \lambda 2) = f\cdot \lambda$ which is equal to the speed of the wave.

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

Many other contributors have provided a correct "solution" to your problem but I will replicate it here for completeness along with some additional information that may help to build some intuition and clarify the problem.

### Solution

In the equation you cited (replicated for completeness)

$$ c = \sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}} \tag{1} \label{string-velocity} $$

with $c$ corresponding to the perturbation (i.e. wave) propagation speed which you denoted $v$, $T$ denotes tension and $\mu$ the linear density. Thus, $T \neq \frac{1}{f}$ where $f$ is the temporal frequency. Furthermore, it is apparent that $c$ is **not** dependent on frequency. On the contrary, it is obvious that the propagation velocity/speed depends solely on the medium. This is, on (linear in this case) density $\mu$ and tension $T$. Just as a note here, equation \eqref{string-velocity} gives the propagation speed for a string.

### Solution to further question in comments

You additionally commented that the problem "persists" for the equation

$$ c = \lambda f \tag{2} \label{fundamental-wave-equation} $$

with $\lambda$ denoting the wavelength.

Again, there's various ways that this equation could be satisfied. One could very well double $f$ and $c$ for the equation to hold. Alternatively, one could double $f$ and halve $\lambda$ and the equation would still hold. The former is what actually holds resulting in constant propagation speed. Thus, for two frequencies $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ with $f_{2} = 2 \cdot f{1}$, by plugging the values in equation \eqref{fundamental-wave-equation} and dividing the two equations you would get

$$ \frac{c_{1}}{c_{2}} = \frac{\lambda_{1} f_{1}}{\lambda_{2} f_{2}} \xrightarrow{c_{1} = c_{2}} 1 = \frac{\lambda_{1} f_{1}}{\lambda_{2} f_{2}} \implies \lambda_{2} f_{2} = \lambda_{1} f_{1} \implies \frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}} = \frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}} \xrightarrow{f_{2} = 2 f_{1}} \frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}} = \frac{f_{1}}{2 \cdot f_{1}} \implies \frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}} = \frac{1}{2} \implies \lambda_{2} = \frac{\lambda_{1}}{2} \tag{2} \label{wavelength-relation} $$

which as you may already know holds for all cases in the same medium. Of course, things are different when the perturbation changes media, where the quantity that changes is the propagation speed, $c$, resulting in a change in the wavelength, $\lambda$ (it is important to note that the frequency does **not** change from one medium to the other as it is a characteristic of the source and not of the medium).

### Additional remarks

Equation \eqref{string-velocity} has the general form of the perturbation propagation speed for all linear waves in non-dispersive media. The general form is

$$ c = \sqrt{\frac{B}{\rho}} \tag{3} \label{wave-speed} $$

where in this equation $B$ denotes some kind of force inside the medium (apologise for the abuse of terminology) where in the string case you cited is defined by the tension of the string and in fluids it is denoted by the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus). Additionally, $\rho$ is the density of the medium with $\mu$ denoting the linear density since we refer to a 1D problem, but in general $\rho$ is the volume density in 3D.

As is apparent, both quantities are independent of the source and are characteristics of the medium. Thus, the wave propagation speed is defined entirely by the medium.

Below ("Domino sound speed video" below) you can see a nice video depicting exactly that. You will see that the domino pieces that are more densely positioned will fall faster than those that are further away from each other. In the video, it is apparent that the propagation speed in a sense, depends on the average "interaction"$^{*}$ time between particles (how often one particle "interacts" with the others).

[Domino sound speed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlENwMSTUy4&feature=youtu.be)

$^{*}$ Please note that the particles can "interact"/collide with the neighbouring ones due to thermal noise but here, we refer to the "interaction" due to the perturbation which is superimposed to the "thermal interactions" and adds some kind of "order" to the total movement. This is a vague approximation to build some insight and is not a description of the actual phenomena taking place.